# MESSAGE LIST COMPONENT: Is it possible limit who the users can message in OOTB way?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I would like to know if it is possible to have any solution to limit who some users can message based on the profile or any other way with OOTB settings.

Comment: Can you add some clarification to what _message_ you are referring to Do you mean EmailMessage? Lightning Message Service? Chatter? Emp?

Comment: The message list component on the B2B storefront, for example.